# Capsule exception when running Corda nodes

Tags: corda

I am trying to run Corda nodes on macOS El Capitan with JDK 1.8.0_60 by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html.

I am getting the following error:

> CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Could not parse version: -9.0.1 while processing
>   system property java.home:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse version: -9.0.1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Corda nodes requires a JDK version greater than JDK 8u121. If you upgrade your JDK, this error will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Although its older thread, i encountered it today and stumbled upon this page and thought to share my findings.

Actually Oracle changed the numbering style from **java9** (like **9.0.1**) and it seems you have it installed. You will have to point to **jdk 1.8.x** so make it work until capsule is updated to work with java9.

Comment: Also, Corda does not support Java 9 or 10 as of Corda 3.2.